# Openstack nova-api - HTTP exception thrown: Hypervisor with ID '1' could not be found for removed compute/hypervisor

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Hypervisor with ID 1 was removed but getting exceptions

nova-api.log:

```
2017-01-09 19:27:21.067 43051 INFO nova.api.openstack.wsgi [req-27e511e0-cb85-4794-8f11-c00cec17717c 886b00b75d0b45c1936b30d579860bb7 e7375d9b17944ec49b4cf81d23945e7a - - -] HTTP exception thrown: Hypervisor with ID '1' could not be found.
```

That Host was removed from compute_nodes table

```
mysql> SELECT id, created_at, updated_at, hypervisor_hostname FROM compute_nodes;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+
| id | created_at          | updated_at          | hypervisor_hostname    |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+
|  3 | 2016-05-16 18:17:09 | 2017-01-09 19:19:24 | oscompute30.domain.dom |
|  4 | 2016-05-19 21:52:29 | 2016-06-10 20:49:28 | oscompute31.domain.dom |
|  5 | 2016-08-06 00:57:08 | 2017-01-09 19:19:27 | oscompute31.domain.dom |
|  6 | 2016-08-29 21:56:24 | 2017-01-09 19:20:15 | oscompute32.domain.dom |
|  7 | 2016-09-07 17:38:10 | 2017-01-09 19:19:48 | oscompute28.domain.dom |
|  8 | 2016-09-20 11:47:47 | 2017-01-09 19:19:51 | oscompute29.domain.dom |
|  9 | 2016-10-17 18:47:50 | 2017-01-09 19:19:34 | oscompute33.domain.dom |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also doesn't show up in `nova service-list`

```
root@oscontrollerpr3:~# nova service-list
+----+------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
| Id | Binary           | Host            | Zone     | Status  | State | Updated_at                 | Disabled Reason |
+----+------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
| 1  | nova-cert        | oscontrollerpr3 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-01-09T19:42:36.000000 | -               |
| 2  | nova-consoleauth | oscontrollerpr3 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-01-09T19:42:31.000000 | -               |
| 3  | nova-scheduler   | oscontrollerpr3 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-01-09T19:42:35.000000 | -               |
| 4  | nova-conductor   | oscontrollerpr3 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-01-09T19:42:36.000000 | -               |
| 12 | nova-compute     | oscompute28     | Zone1    | enabled | up    | 2017-01-09T19:42:30.000000 | -               |
| 13 | nova-compute     | oscompute29     | Zone2    | enabled | up    | 2017-01-09T19:42:34.000000 | -               |
| 14 | nova-compute     | oscompute30     | Zone1    | enabled | up    | 2017-01-09T19:42:31.000000 | -               |
| 16 | nova-compute     | oscompute31     | Zone2    | enabled | up    | 2017-01-09T19:42:30.000000 | -               |
| 17 | nova-compute     | oscompute32     | Zone1    | enabled | up    | 2017-01-09T19:42:31.000000 | -               |
| 18 | nova-compute     | oscompute33     | Zone2    | enabled | up    | 2017-01-09T19:42:31.000000 | -               |
+----+------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: You don't have a hypervisor with ID 1. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: There are exceptions in the logs saying it does not exist. (log msg at the top of post). I think its causing slowness, page loads in the UI are slow and thats the message I keep seeing in the logs.